# Keras: Save the hidden states for each timestep into file while training an LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

For visualization purposes in a Keras LSTM model, I need to save a file containing all the emitted hidden states at each time step. I was wondering if there is any way to do this. Any idea or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Forgive an ignorant question, what do you mean "emitted hidden states?"

Comment: No problem! I basically mean the output of each LSTM cell.